# Filtering an existing SeleniumElement

Tags: java, selenium

I have a SeleniumElement that represents a couple of elements on the page, and I would like to filter it to only include `":visible"` elements.

I might be able to refine the original constructor to only contain one elemnent, but I'm asking if I can do something different: given a particular element, create a new element that filters on this element's selector.

Something like this:

```
public static SeleniumElement visible(SeleniumElement element) {
    // Locator.filter() doesn't really exist, the next line won't compile
    By locator = element.getElementLocator().filter(":visible"); 
    return new SeleniumElement(element.getName(), locator, element.getPage());
}

visible(myButton).click();

// Calling myButton.click() fails because there are multiple elements that match
// the selector. However, only one of them is visible right now
```

Comment: Sorry, I was using an internal wrapper we have for Selenium and didn't notice that actually a wrapper, I thought this was Selenium code that I can't edit (Selenium has no SeleniumElement class!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to filter the elements via their visibility then Using CSS Selector would be a good choice.

I have added both css properties Display and Visibility. Hence you can use any one property/attribute by which you can find the target element. (C# Code)

```
IWebElement Query = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Element Xpath")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("[@style='display: block;Visibility: hidden']"));
```

I hope this helps. All the Best :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was using an internal wrapper we have for Selenium and didn't notice that actually a wrapper, I thought this was Selenium code that I can't edit (Selenium has no `SeleniumElement` class!)

Answer (score 0):

or you can perform click based on the element is visible or not.

```
    if (element.Visible)
    {
        element.click();
    }
```